# Multiplicative Order when for integers $m > 2, n > 0$, when $2^m | (3^n - 1)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction, multiplicative-order

It seems to me that for integers $m>2, n>0$, when $2^m | (3^n - 1)$, that the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) is $2^{m-2}$ so that for $0 < i < 2^{m-2}$, $3^i \not\equiv 1 \pmod {2^m}$ and $3^{2^{m-2}}\equiv 1 \pmod {2^m}$

I am having trouble completing the inductive argument.

Here's what I came up with for the base case. For $m=3$, $2^3 | (3^n-1)$ if and only if $2 | n$ since $3^{2t+1} \equiv 3\times9^t \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ and $3^{2t} \equiv 9^t \equiv 1^t \pmod 8$

Assume that up to some $m \ge 3$, $2^m | (3^n - 1)$ if and only if $2^{m-2} | n$

Assume that $2^{m+1} |(3^n-1)$.  It follows that there exists an integer $a$ such that $n = 2^{m-2}a$.

Assume that $a$ is odd.  It seems to me that it should be possible to complete this argument through a contradiction.  I am not clear how to finish the argument.

Comment: FYI, a fairly closely related question is [Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $3^{2^{n}}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424304/602049), although that one just asks to prove divisibility rather than it being specifically the multiplicative order. Also, there's [Prove that $2^{n+2}$ is a divisor of the number $k^{2^{n}}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3381826/602049), showing the divisibility applies to all odd integers, not just $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note with $n = 2^{m-2}a$ that

$$3^n - 1 = (3^{2^{m-2}} - 1)(\color{blue}{3^{2^{m-2}(a-1)} + 3^{2^{m-2}(a-2)} + \ldots + 3^{2^{m-2}} + 1}) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

There are $a$ terms in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$. If $a$ is odd, then since each term is odd, the sum will also be odd.